# How to make HTML div follow its page position while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

So I have a page like this you look at. On top I have some special informative div (here it contains something like links to | logout | about | faq | search ). I want on page scrolling (down) that div follow page like it stands above it. I want it to work in IE 5,6,7,8,9 and FF 1.5 and above. How to solve such problem?

If your answer contains JS it shall be libs (like jQuery) independent. If html - No frames, Iframes

Comment: Just curious...why you want it to work in IE 5 and 6? Corporate intranet thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do is create a div that take the full page (but a fixed header for your top div) and has the `overflow:scroll` CSS attribute.

If you want a "float over" you can use the CSS `position:fixed` style.